# Billing address issues

Tags: orders, credit-card

Is there a way to bypass the billing address when buying something online. I have been ask of my billing address and I don’t know how to get it to them.

Answer (score 0):

After a complete error testing I found as part of an answer on a different stackexchange question.

```
                unset($jsLayoutResult['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                    ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$key]);

            }
        }
```

The problem with this is that if a shop uses checkout-agreements that those will also be deleted. Anyone know how to fix this?